# Openlayers compilation error with React Next

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using the openlayers library with React Next.Adding the openlayers library with npm. But when I import the "import Map from 'ol / Map'" library, I get the following error.

```
import PluggableMap from './PluggableMap.js';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.ol/Map.js     at Object.ol/Map.js (<path>\.next\server\static\development\pages\index.js:1730:18)
at __webpack_require__ (<path>\.next\server\static\development\pages\index.js:23:31)
at Module../components/mappanel/map.js (<path>\.next\server\static\development\pages\index.js:557:67)
at __webpack_require__ (<path>\.next\server\static\development\pages\index.js:23:31)
at Module../pages/index.js (<path>\.next\server\static\development\pages\index.js:1302:83)
at __webpack_require__ <path>\.next\server\static\development\pages\index.js:23:31)
```

I didn't do anything in the next.config.js and .babelrc files.How to resolve the error?

Note: Openlayers, working with classic react.

Sandbox link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-openlayers-7r04v

Thanks,

Comment: I can't reproduce. try making a minimal reproduction example in codesandbox

Comment: @evgenifotia I added the sandbox link to the question

Comment: so it worked for me before because I haven't restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `ol` doesn't work in server side because it require window and such stuff so you need to do this instead

```
componentDidMount() {
   const map = require("ol/Map").default;
}
```

Comment: @İlkayTaşkıran If this solve your issue mark the answer as answered ✔